# Return filtered results in array

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML `button`s:

```
<button name="foo" class="one active">cat</button>
<button name="foo" class="one active">dog</button>
<button name="foo" class="one active">hamster</button>
<button name="foo" class="one">rhino</button>
<button name="foo" class="one">rat</button>
```

Given the following `jQuery` code:

```
var res = $('button[name=foo]', '#my-form').filter(function () {
    return $(this).hasClass('active');
}).text();
```

`res` ends up with the string `"catdoghamster"` when I would have expected the result in an array such as `["cat", "dog", "hamster"]`.

How do I filter the above buttons based on a class and return the `text` of the buttons in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted a map in addition to the filter, and then to return the text inside the map, not after it

```js
var res = $('button[name=foo]', '#my-form').filter(function() {
  return $(this).hasClass('active');
}).map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="my-form">
  <button name="foo" class="one active">cat</button>
  <button name="foo" class="one active">dog</button>
  <button name="foo" class="one active">hamster</button>
  <button name="foo" class="one">rhino</button>
  <button name="foo" class="one">rat</button>
</form>
```

As a sidenote, the filter seems uneccessary, as you could just do

```
$('button[name=foo].active', '#my-form')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't use `.filter()`, but works in the scenario you've given

```
var res = [];
$("button[name=foo].active").each(function(){ res.push($(this).text()})
```

This works given that the selector is good enough.